# How to pass template text to a view programmatically without using a file?

Tags: python, plone

I'm writing some tests and I need to use templates in my view without using a file (e.g. via `ViewPageTemplateFile`). The template must evaluate the tal expressions and access the functions of the view. Here is my current problem. I get an error on evaluating the `view` in the PageTemplate. I'm not sure whether my code follows best practices.

```python
from plone.app.testing import TEST_USER_NAME, TEST_USER_PASSWORD
from plone.testing.z2 import Browser
from zope.component import getGlobalSiteManager
from zope.publisher.interfaces.browser import IBrowserView
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate import PageTemplate

class MyView(BrowserView):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
    def render(self):
        template = PageTemplate()
        text = '''\
<div tal:on-error="string:view fails"><span tal:replace="view/var"/></div>
<div tal:on-error="string:python fails"><span tal:replace="python:'python works'"/></div>
            '''
        template.write(text)
        return template()
    def __call__(self):
        return self.render()
    def var(self):
        return 'my_value'

global_site_manager = getGlobalSiteManager()
global_site_manager.registerAdapter(MyView, (None, None), IBrowserView, 'my_view')

browser=Browser(app.Plone)
browser.addHeader('Authorization',
                  'Basic %s:%s' % (TEST_USER_NAME, TEST_USER_PASSWORD))
browser.open(app.Plone.absolute_url() + '/@@my_view')
print browser.contents
```

produces following output:

```
<div>view fails</div>
<div>
    python works
</div>
```

Comment: I see no motivation for not using a file here

Comment: The code of the template is generated with different results depending on different parameters. In our case depending on the Schemata of the context. I could of course generate (and latter remove) files on the file system. But our generic programmic approach make us feel better if we don't generate anything.

Comment: What I mean is that zpt is a template language, if you have part of HTML that you want conditionally import you can still use a .pt file.

However... I think that if you really really want to not use a file your workaround can be good enough.

Comment: After searching the sources I was no able to find a Template class with the requested functionality. My only workaround was to subclass `PageTemplate` and pass the instance and the context to its namespace. See my answer. But I'd like to know whether there is another approach to this issue.

Comment: @keul You're absolutely right. And this is the usual way to do it. Actually we do it so. But my question, for our particular case addresses the possibility to pass the template **without using** a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround until now is to create my own `class MyPageTemplate(PageTemplate)`, passing the view's instance as argument in the constructor, and override `pt_getContext` to populate the namespace with `view`, `context`, and `request` from the instance.

I would like to know whether there is a better solution (best practices).

Here my workaround:

```python
from plone.app.testing import TEST_USER_NAME
from plone.app.testing import TEST_USER_PASSWORD
from plone.testing.z2 import Browser
from zope.component import getGlobalSiteManager
from zope.publisher.interfaces.browser import IBrowserView
from Products.Five.browser import BrowserView
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
from zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate import PageTemplate
from zope.interface import Interface
from zope.publisher.browser import IDefaultBrowserLayer

class MyPageTemplate(PageTemplate):
    instance = None
    def __init__(self, instance):
        self.instance = instance
    def pt_getContext(self, instance, request, **kw):
        namespace = super(MyPageTemplate, self).pt_getContext(**kw)
        namespace['view'] = self.instance
        namespace['context'] = self.instance.context
        namespace['request'] = self.instance.request
        return namespace

class MyView(BrowserView):
    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request
    def render(self):
        template = MyPageTemplate(self)
        text = '''\
<div tal:on-error="string:request fails">request<span tal:replace="structure request"/> works</div>
<div tal:on-error="string:context fails">context/id=<span tal:replace="context/id"/> works</div>
<div tal:on-error="string:view fails">view/my_var=<span tal:replace="view/my_var"/> works</div>
<div tal:on-error="string:python fails"><span tal:replace="python:'python works'"/></div>
            '''
        template.write(text)
        return template()
    def __call__(self):
        return self.render()
    def my_var(self):
        return 'my_value'

global_site_manager = getGlobalSiteManager()
global_site_manager.registerAdapter(MyView, (None, None), IBrowserView, 'my_view')

browser=Browser(app.Plone)
browser.addHeader('Authorization', 'Basic %s:%s' % (TEST_USER_NAME, TEST_USER_PASSWORD))
browser.open(app.Plone.absolute_url() + '/@@my_view')
print browser.contents
```